# Microsoft Teams Tab SSO getAuthToken returning resourceDisabled

Tags: reactjs, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working in a multitenanted teams app, and wanted to add a tab to the bot using SSO.  In my development environment this is all working fine and I can log in with no issues.  When I deploy this to the QA environment, I'm getting the following error

```
AUTHMSAL: Event: adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_resource|AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://[mydomain]/[myappid] was not found in the tenant named [tenant]. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: d9eae514-36e0-4c28-afeb-3312133b0a01
Correlation ID: 82e84904-a4ef-490a-a114-b5efb68eb701
Timestamp: 2021-05-14 15:22:47Z, resource: api://[mydomain]/[myappid], action: resourceDisabled
```

I'm not sure why this is failing.  I have checked the tenant in QA and confirmed my app is listed under "Enterprise Applications", and the permissions have been consented to, and granted Admin Consent.  I have also checked if there were any differences (other than URI names) in the setup of my app registration for my development env and qa env, and there are none.

Here is the code I'm using to try and retrieve the AuthToken

```js
const authTokenRequest: microsoftTeams.authentication.AuthTokenRequest = {
  successCallback: function (token: string) {
    const decoded: { [key: string]: any; } = jwt.decode(token);
    localStorage.setItem("name", decoded.name);
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  },
  failureCallback: function (error: any) {
    console.log("Failure on getAuthToken: " + error);
  }
};

microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
  microsoftTeams.getContext((r) => {
    microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken(authTokenRequest);
  });
});
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Nothing on this at all?

Comment: Hi @entropic, we are looking into it and checking with our internal team, we will update you soon.

Comment: This question is tracking from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/532.

Comment: @entropic - Were you able to resolve your issue?
I am getting the same error. How were you able to get it working in the dev env. What all steps did you follow. Any documentation that you followed?

Comment: @Anand it's still broken for me, just tried it yesterday and attached the error to the link Jagadeesh provided.  In the meantime I'm not using SSO anymore and doing an auth popup instead.

Comment: Getting the same problem still

Answer (score 3):

@entropic @Anand @Jagadeesh-MSFT

I had a similar situation, receiving a **resourceDisabled** error from **getAuthToken** when i tested a tab app created based on the Microsoft provided sample
[Microsoft Teams - Tabs Azure AD Single Sign-On Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs)

[img][resourceDisabled returned from getAuthToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya08R.png)

What i did was correcting the AppID within the **webApplicationInfo.resource** element according to this
[Manifest file has incorrect/static resource url #3](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs/issues/3)

I can now get the right result:

[img][getAuthToken is now successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LByvx.png)

Note: i also updated the schema version from 1.5 to 1.9, but it seems this change was not relevant to the issue.

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.9",
```

Comment: I've triple checked the manifest, and still getting the same error.  As mentioned in the comments above this is actually being tracked here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/532